# Run svn rename on many files in a folder matching a specific pattern

Tags: svn

Given a folder with files using a design name as part of the file, I want to run `svn rename` on matches to the design name. The directory listing showing the files (more than shown here) has this format:

```
    reg_ptst_lib_ptst_rtl_12.ngc
    reg_ptst_lib_ptst_rtl_13.ngc
    reg_ptst_lib_ptst_rtl_14.ngc
    reg_ptst_lib_ptst_rtl_15.ngc
```

The design name string is ptst.
I want to have the script iterate over each file, executing something like this command:

```
$svn rename reg_ptst_lib_ptst_rtl_12.ngc reg_scst3_lib_scst3_rtl_12.ngc
```

to change the design name from `ptst` to `scst3` in subversion.

Comment: Does it have to be in ruby or perl? You can do this with `find` and `awk`

Comment: Please tell us what kind of language you want to use to achieve this?

Comment: Prefer Perl, however it would be instructive to see the find-awk and a Ruby.

Comment: @Mikef already added an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to use ruby or perl, here's an example with `find`, `awk` and `bash`. In the directory containing your files:

```
find *.ngc | awk '{ str=$0; gsub(/ptst/,"scst3",str); print "svn rename " $0 " " str }' | bash
```

You can test this first by removing the final `| bash`, which prints out the svn rename command to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Same method as Jon, just adding quotes around file names in case anyone else (like me) wanted to do a similar operation when the filenames contain spaces.

```
find *.ngc | awk '{ str=$0; gsub(/ptst/,"scst3",str); print "svn rename \"" $0 "\" \"" str "\""}' | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put to work the total commander + windows batch files for this task (called `tacklebar` project). You can adopt to use any other commander like Far or Double Commander as long as it can calls scripts with arguments for selected files by keyboard shortcut or by toolbar button (currently the installer supports only the Total Commander).

The idea is to select the files/directories you want for rename (does not matter here are they under version control or not) in a commander application and put them into the temporary created text file (Total Commander does it automatically through the `%L` variable) and then call the script to rename the paths selected by that list file.

The script just copy the list file into 2 temporary list files and opens, for example, Notepad++ to edit the second list file. After you done renaming the files in the Notepad++ you close the editor and saves changes, after that the script compares the 2 lists and does the renaming.

You can install the script and all other scripts into the Total Commander buttons bar by run `_install.bat` from:

https://github.com/andry81/tacklebar/tree/HEAD/

To install 3d party dependencies run `_install.bat` from:

https://github.com/andry81-3dparty/tacklebar--external_tools/tree/HEAD/